# Tikz: Globally set an inner separation for labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

Instead of defining the `inner xsep` for every node (like in b), I would like to set this globally.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[label above/.append style={inner xsep=50pt}]
\node (a) [draw=black] [label={[draw=red]above:xyz}] {a};

\node [below of=a,draw=black] [label={[inner xsep=50pt,draw=red]above:xyz}] {b};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want this for all labels or only the above ones (e.g. the red ones in your image)?

Comment: @samcarter I guess for all label would be done by `label/.append style={inner xsep=50pt}` correct? I don't want the nodes `a` and `b` to get bigger. I guess for me it wouldn't matter if labels below (not use here) are effected, but I don't think, that this will change anything

Comment: You can use the `every label` style...

Comment: @PaulGaborit but this would effect the labels inside nodes and thereby the node size, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `every label`. (**EDIT**: Uuuups, I just see [Paul Gaborit's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470691/tikz-globally-set-an-inner-separation-for-labels/470722#comment1185956_470691) now. Full credit to him, if I had seen it before I wouldn't have written this answer. Sorry!)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.append style={inner xsep=50pt}]
\node (a) [draw=black] [label={[draw=red]above:xyz}] {a};

\node [below of=a,draw=black] [label={[draw=red]above:xyz}] {b};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Here is the good solution for which I did not take the time to write an answer. Fortunately, marmots never take a nap. ;-)